# Transforming into another object using LINQ Grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of exams which has happened on a particular time, and the mark obtained by a student for that Exam contained in an object as below:

```
class Exam
{
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    public double? Mark { get; set; }
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I need to transform this into another format for display purposes using the following structure:

```
class ExamViewModel
{
    public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
    public double? Mark { get; set; }
    List<StudentVieWModel> Students { get; set; }
}

class StudentVieWModel
{
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class ResultViewModel
{
    List<ExamViewModel>  Exams { get; set; }
}
```

Basically what I want ot display is an exam which has taken place at a particuar date, and the total marks achieved in that by all student (S1 = 10, S2 = 20, Total = 30 at 19/06/2014). The students should be transformed into the Student ViewModel so that I can see who all students have attended the exam. How can I do this using LINQ?

Thanks,
-Mike

**Note**: Using .NET4

Tried:

```
exams.OrderBy(x=>x.DateTime)
     .GroupBy(x => x.DateTime, x=> x, (d, students) => new{Date= x, Students = students.ToList()} );
```

But cant get the total of marks..:(

Comment: This looks like straightforward work, to me. What have you tried? Where are you stuck at? What are your difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cleaner IMHO to use a `GroupBy` with a subsequent `Select` instead of using the overload of `GroupBy` that includes a projection:

```
var query = 
    exams.GroupBy(x => x.DateTime)
         .Select(g => new {
                              Date = g.Key, 
                              TotalMarks = g.Sum(s => s.Mark)
                          }
                );
```